# mysql GRANT + WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

I want to give permissions only to specificated rows in mysql.
table: messages
cols: from, to, message

`GRANT ALL ON db.messages TO 'jeffrey'@'localhost' WHERE messages.from = 'jeffrey' OR messages.to = 'jeffrey' ;`

With a thing like this the user only can access only his own messages.

Do you know how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [`GRANT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html) command, there is no ability to set permission-levels on a per-row basis (table/columns, yes - but not the individual rows).

You could setup a [View](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) to handle this though and grant the user permission to access the view instead.

A view such as the following should give you the messages based on the current user:

```
CREATE VIEW user_messages AS
    SELECT *
    FROM messages
    WHERE
        messages.from = user() OR messages.to = user();
```

And the grant-statement should be similar:

```
GRANT ALL ON db.user_messages TO 'jeffrey'@'localhost';
```

Comment: It's worked correctly, i have only added `SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(),'@',1)` so i have `root` only, not `root@localhost`

Comment: Awesome! I've never done it before, but I've always wanted to set something up like this myself =P. I'm glad it worked out for you =]

Comment: Thank you very much! I've connected it with jquery and php and everything is fine. :)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't have row-level permissions. You have database, table, and column. not rows. For row-level, use a view and/or approriate `where` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

If you want row level permissions, you'll have to add your own mechanism.
Usually it's an integer, used as a bit Pattern

E.g. 0x0002 is a Supervisor Level access

The user Fred is a supervisor so their Permission is 0x0002 and they have a UserId of 23

Then something like

```
Select * From SomeTable
inner Join myUsers On MyUsers.UserID = 23 and (SomeTable.PermissionID & MyUsers.PermissionID) > 0
```

So Fred can only access rows with a permissionId where bit 1 (Big endian !) is set.

Have a deep think though it's major PIA to maintain.